# Can I deploy Kubernetes Dashboard in offline environment?

Tags: kubernetes, offline, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm new to Kubernetes. Recently, I was successfull to manage kubernetes with online server. But, when I move to isolated area (offline server) all of my environment running well except when I deploy some images. The different just internet connection.

First of all, I want to deploy kubernetes dashboard to make me easy to maintain Kubernetes. Can I deploy kubernetes dashboard in offline mode ?

Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashboard only needs to be able to talk to the Kubernetes API. It doesn't have an "online" or "offline" mode. As with all air-gapped networks, you would need a local image proxy or similar to transfer the container image to your local network. How you implement that is up to you and well out of the scope of the dashboard.